# Como fazer um explode sem retornar valores vazios?

Tags: php

No PHP podemos dividir uma *string* e transformá-la em `array`.

Exemplo:

```
$url = 'pagina/id/1';

explode('/', $url);
```

Resultado:

> ['pagina', 'id', '1']

Porém, se essa url tivesse uma barra antes e depois, retornaria alguns valores vazios.

```
$url = '/pagina/id/1/';

explode('/', $url);
```

> ['', 'pagina', 'id', '1', '']

Como poderia fazer pra que esses valores vazios não seja retornados (sem ter que usar `array_filter`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando a função `preg_split` do PHP, que aceita algumas `flags` especiais para determinados casos.

Nesse casos, será necessário utilizar a `flag` `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`

Veja:

```
preg_split('/\//', $url, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Resultado:

> ['pagina', 'id', '1']

**Observação**: Nesse caso, como `preg_split` usa expressões regulares, é necessário escapar alguns caracteres, ou, como alternativa, utilizar a função `preg_quote`.

**Atualização**: Lembrando que `preg_split` com `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` removerá todos os valores vazios do resultado, inclusive os "do meio", como no caso de `/pagina//id//1`.

Comment: pode-se usar outro limitador para a preg, em vez de usar `/` como limitador pode-se usar `#`, `@`, `~`, ficando `~/~`, `#/#`, `@/@`

Answer (score 2):

Seria uma boa questão se a pergunta fosse sem o uso de *expressões regulares*. Não vejo real motivo para usar *ER* em algo que é tão simples. Há várias recomendações sobre o uso moderado das *ER's*.

Se o caso é específico e o intuito é simplesmente remover as `/` no inicio e no final para evitar a criação de índices vazios, então eu faria uso da função [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php).

---

```
$url = explode( '/', trim( '/pagina/id/1/' , '/' ) );
print_r( $url );

// output
Array
(
    [0] => pagina
    [1] => id
    [2] => 1
)
```

Exemplo no [*Ideone*](http://ideone.com/SLJq9g).

Comment: Concordo sobre as expressões regulares em alguns casos serem ruins, mas você concorda comigo que seu código teria problemas caso o usuário passasse na url a seguinte expressão `'pagina//id//1' `? O `trim` só serve para limpar o final e o início. No caso do `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` ele eliminaria tudo que fosse vazio

Comment: `array_filter` limpa os índices vazios da url `pagina//id//1`. Aind anão vejo motivo para ER na url ``'pagina//id//1'`.

Comment: Se eu usasse da foram que você fez com `pagina//id//1`, retornaria isso `array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "pagina"
  [1] =>
  string(0) ""
  [2] =>
  string(2) "id"
  [3] =>
  string(0) ""
  [4] =>
  string(1) "1"
}
`

Comment: Você acha que seria um ganho usar `array_filter(explode())` ao invés de `preg_split` (não é uma pergunta sarcástica, é sincera mesmo) ?

Comment: Eu não gosto de url que aceita barras múltiplas seguidas como `pagina//id//1`. Talvez eu usasse o próprio htaccess para *ajustar* essa url e remover as duplicatas.

Comment: Wallace, há muitos casos onde um parâmetro de URL pode vir vazio, uma paginação no formato url amigável, por exemplo. Mantenho sistemas diversos que fazem isso e não somente para paginação. Exemplo, para envio de flags em formulários segmentados. Por isso, se eliminar as barras duplas, a ordem dos parâmetros, no caso de url amigável, conflitariam. O mais importante é manter a integridade dos parâmetros. Se vai vir vazio, ou com número ou letra errada, isso é responsabilidade do model (mvc).

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário usar expressão regular, use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php), acho que é a forma mais curta de fazer:

```
<?php
array_diff(explode('/', '/pagina//id//1'), array(''));

// resultado:
array (
  1 => 'pagina',
  3 => 'id',
  5 => '1',
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Também é possível obter o mesmo resultado, com a função [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

```
<?php

$str = "//pagina//id/1//";
$item = strtok($str,'/');
$arr[] = $item;

while($item = strtok('/')){
    $arr[] = $item;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

[Exemplo - ideonline](https://ideone.com/RcXW2d)

Comment: Muito bom! Alguém lembrou do `strtok`!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, para esse caso não parece muito prático mas é uma opção.

Answer (score 1):

Faça um tratamento básico antes de usar o `explode()`.

Abaixo, um exemplo com `trim()` e `strpos()`

```
$str = '/a/b/c/';
$str = trim($str, '/');
if( strpos( $str, '/' ) )
{
    $arr = explode('/',$str);
    print_r($arr);
}

/*
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
*/
```

Note que não estamos considerando uma string com o valor `$str = '/a//c/';` que resultaria em

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => 
    [2] => c
)
```

Nesse caso, deve-se avaliar o modelo de negócios, se permite ou não valores vazios.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `array_diff()`:

```
$teste ='/a/b/c/d';

$saida = array_diff(explode('/', $teste), array('', null));

print_r($saida);
```

Comment: Acho que essa resposta já está dada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81902/4995